# Can keycloak javascript adapter use OpenIDConnect against Identity Server?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, keycloak, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a Vue/Javascript app that uses the keycloak Javascript adapter to communicate with keycloak, and this works fine. But now we need to deploy the app to another platform where we'll have to use a different identity provider (IdentityServer). It supports OIDC, so my question is - is the Javascript adapter able to talk to this provider using OIDC, or do I need to switch to a different library to be able to talk to something else than keycloak?

I have tried this, but is getting an error message saying the GET command is not valid. I suspect/hope this is just due to some invalid config settings when specifying realm and clientid, but it would be great to hear if others have made this approach work, or possibly understand why it will not work with other providers than keycloak.  In advance, thanks for your help!